# Как переключать кнопки автоматически каждую неделю?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть 2 кнопки. 1 неделя и 2 неделя. Мне нужно чтобы они переключались каждую неделю автоматически. (Кнопка в синей форме обозначает, что она сейчас активна) Чтобы в 1,3 и 5ю неделю была активна 1 кнопка, а в 2,4 и 6ю неделю была активна 2 кнопка. Скажите пожалуйста как мне это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может у вас есть какая то начальная дата, которая являетсфя первой неделей? Чтобы от неё отсчитывать количество недель до текущего дня.

Comment: Можно взять количество недель в году. Это не сойдет?

Comment: как это поможет?

Comment: я про то, что 2020й год заканчивается на 52й неделе, 2021й год начинается с 1й недели. И это одна и та же неделя. А вот 2023й год заканчивется в вкоскресенье, то есть 52я неделя 23го не совпадает с 1й неделей 24го

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar).

```
  Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
  //Номер недели в месяце
  println("Current week of month is : " + now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH));
  //Номер недели в году
  println("Current week of year is : " + now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
```

Далее все просто, смотрим какая неделя и включаем нужную кнопку.

Comment: Я именно так и сделал. Только дело в том что например: В прошлом месяце было 5 недель и оно заканчивалось в 1й кнопке. Начинается 1 неделя другого месяца и она остаётся там же на 1й кнопке,а я хочу чтобы она перешла на 2ю кнопку. Я пытался написать логическую часть но не смог. Вы можете на словах хотя бы написать мне логическую часть? А код я сам напишу

Comment: @mr.hinkal05 в таком случае, наверно стоит ориентироваться на номер недели в году.